# Make nodejs function sequential for one user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an nodejs app with an express API handling users and starting http requests for a webapp.

How can I make a specific function's execution sequential on a per user basis? i.e. queue calls from one user, but have another user's calls queued parallel

Does that make sense?

I found a lot of libraries that queue calls - or limit requests on time basis. How would I go about having that on a user basis?

---

EDIT

Example: I have two logged in users. It takes about 3-5 seconds to fully execute myFunction('some http request')

1. user1 calls myFunction() -> gets executed instantly
2. user2 calls myFunction() -> gets executed instantly
3. user2 calls myFunction() again right after, while first call is still processed -> call gets queued until first one finishes. So something like myFunction().then()

Comment: Maybe i am missing something.. Can you show an example? Also why would you want to go sync ? there are no advantages to that route.. If you are trying to call a function that is sync, you can call that inside Promise

Comment: have a queue per user?

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing *synchronous* with *sequential*. Queueing calls is still asynchronous. Please edit your question (title, body and tags) to clarify.

Comment: Well I need to limit the requests to 1 req per user at a time- advantage would be that i control these specific api calls and don't get blocked. I'll try to ad a more clear example to the post...

Comment: @Bergi seems like. changed it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the library that you are trying to use?

Comment: I don't have one. I'm rather looking for "the way to do it". If there is a library for it, though - even better! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not to overcomplicate things you could use '[async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#auto)' module's 'auto' function.

If you pass concurrency (int value) to it, it will run that number of tasks in parallel (at maximum). In our case we pass 1 so the functions are executed sequentially for a special user.
If you don't pass any value, It will run as many parallel tasks as possible.

```js
'use strict';

const async = require('async');
const _ = require('lodash');

//Async function
const myFunction = function (data, cb) {
 setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(data);
  cb(null);
 }, _.random(1, 1000));
};

//Do your logic to understand if the user is 'special'
//So we call the functions sequentially
let isSpecialUser = false;

//Allow only one in parallel if this is a special user
//else - allow as much as possible
let concurrency = isSpecialUser ? 1 : null;

async.auto(
 [
  cb => myFunction('First', cb),
  cb => myFunction('Second', cb),
  cb => myFunction('Third', cb),
 ],
 concurrency,
 () => {
  console.log('All done');
  //Do needed stuff here, all calls are done
  //(sequentially or in parallel depending on a user)
 }
);
```